# MVC action method and pipe in query string parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, query-string, actionmethod

I have a call to a get action method with a list of query string parameters being passed to that method.  A few of those parameters have a pipe '|' in them.  The problem is that I cannot have action method parameters with pipe characters in them.  How do I map a piped querystring parameter to a non-piped C# parameter?  Or is there some other trick that I don't know about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a custom model binder. For example let's suppose that you have the following request:

```
/foo/bar?foos=foo1|foo2|foo3&bar=baz
```

and you would like to bind this request to the following action:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(string[] foos, string bar)
{
    ...
}
```

All you have to do is write a custom model binder:

```
public class PipeSeparatedValuesModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var values = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        if (values == null)
        {
            return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
        }

        return values.AttemptedValue.Split('|');
    }
}
```

and then:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(
    [ModelBinder(typeof(PipeSeparatedValuesModelBinder))] string[] foos, 
    string bar
)
{
    ...
}
```